# Starting Weblogic Admin using WLST

Tags: cloud, weblogic, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have created JCS instance in Oracle cloud. Web logic was started properly.

I stopped the managed Server, Admin Server. Now i want to start the server using WLST. I have done below 
`../setDomainEnv.sh` and then getting error when trying Java `weblogic.WLST`

Problem invoking WLST -

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/i18n/logging/BaseTextFormatter

Answer (score 0):

You got to be careful while setting up the environment for WLST.
Use one of below 2 formats to setup environment for WLST.

```
    source setDomainEnv.sh
    or
    . ./setDomainEnv.sh(Mind you there is a space after first .)
```

Now run java weblogic.WLST. It shouldn't cause any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Praveen. I have tried both the options but i am getting the same error. i have restarted Java cloud Service as well but it seems weblogic is not getting started. I did checked teh space between dots.